# stop movie clip

Tags: flash, movieclip

I want to stop a movie, when it enters the last frame, i did this as below:

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MeiYi extends Sprite{
        private var mainMovie:MovieClip = new MeiYiMain();  //MeiYiMain is build in the library of flash cs4

        function MeiYi():void{
            //stop at last frame
            mainMovie.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, stopMainMovie);
            //trace(mainMovie.totalFrames);
            //mainMovie.gotoAndStop(50);
        }

        private function stopMainMovie(evt:Event):void{
            //trace(mainMovie.currentFrame);
            if (mainMovie.currentFrame == mainMovie.totalFrames){
                mainMovie.stop();  //stop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this did nothing for me, no errors or the thing that i want.
What's wrong with it?
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is just to put:

```
stop();
```

In the last frame of the MovieClip (MeiYiMain). You can do this by selecting it and pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring up the ActionScript panel.

Also see the `totalframes` property in [live docs for class MovieClip](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html):

> The total number of frames in the
>   MovieClip instance.
>
> If the movie clip contains multiple
>   frames, the totalFrames property
>   returns the total number of frames in
>   all scenes in the movie clip.

This may effect it as well later on.

Comment: oh,sorry i missed the infomation:i've draged the MeiYiMan movie on the stage.

Comment: Oh, i know. I am operating a difference instance of MeiYiMain.

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine, which is odd. Try making a class for `MeiYiMain` and adding the listeners within that, rather than from within `MeiYi`.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MeiYiMain extends MovieClip
    {
        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function MeiYiMain()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
        }

        /**
         * Handle
         * @param e Event.ENTER_FRAME
         */
        private function _handle(e:Event):void
        {
            if(currentFrame == totalFrames)
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);

                trace('stopped');
                stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries, might need to make use of the **accept answer** button for @Shannon's answer.